# SQL Server : how does the Replace function work as its acting strange for me

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, replace

I am 'randomising' some strings in a SQL Server table to do a primitive encryption on them.

I have a nested SQL replace function around 35 times (A-Z,1-9) that basically takes every letter in the alphabet and number and replaces it with another letter or number. example of which would be

```
Replace(Replace(Replace('a', 'c'), 'b', 'a'), 'c', 'b')
```

I figured that the replace function would go though a string like 'abc' and replace everything once and stop - 'cab'. It doesn't!

It seems to want to change some characters again resulting in `'abc'->'cab'->'ccb'`.

This is fine except if I have another string called 'aac' this could result in duplicate string and I lose traceability back to original.

Can anyone explain how I could stop REPLACE() partially going back over my string?

```
SELECT * INTO example_temp FROM example;
Update KAP_db.dbo.example_temp Set col1 = replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(
replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(‌​replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(
replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(
replace‌​(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(
col1, 'A', 'N'),'B', 'O'), 'C', 'P'), 'D', 'Q'), 'E', 'R'), 'F', 'S'), 'G', 'T'),
'H', 'U'), 'I', 'V'), 'J', 'W'), 'K', 'X'), 'L', 'Y'), 'M', 'Z'), 'O', 'A'), 'P', 'B'),
'Q', 'C'), 'R', 'D'),'S', 'E'),'T', 'E'),'U', 'E'),'V', 'F'),'W', 'G'),'X', 'H'),
'Y', 'I'),'Z', 'J'), '1', '9'),'2','8'),'3','7'),'4','6'),'5','5'),'6','4'),'7','3'),
'8','2'),'9','1'),' ','');
```

The above results in '8EVHUAB' and '8EVHHAB' both outputting '2DFEENA'

Update -------------------------------------------------------------------

Ok i have redone the code and so far have:

```
 DECLARE @Input AS VarChar(1000)
 DECLARE @i AS TinyInt
 Declare @Substring AS VarChar(1000)
 Declare @Prestring  AS VarChar(1000)
 Declare @Poststring  AS VarChar(1000)

 Select @Input='ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ123456789'

 SELECT @i = 1
 Select @Substring ='na'
 WHILE @i <= LEN(@Input) BEGIN

Select @Prestring = SUBSTRING(@Input,-1,@i)
Select @Poststring = SUBSTRING(@Input,@i+1,LEN(@Input))




 SELECT @Substring =  replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace
(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace
(SUBSTRING(@Input,@i,1), 'A', 'N'),'B', 'O'), 'C', 'P'), 'D', 'Q'), 'E', 'R'), 'F', 'S'), 'G', 'T'), 'H', 'U'), 'I', 'V'), 'J', 'W'), 'K', 'X'), 'L', 'Y'), 'M', 'Z'), 'N', 'A'), '0', 'B'), 'P', 'C')
, 'Q', 'D'),'R', 'E'),'S', 'E'),'T', 'E'),'U', 'F'),'V', 'G'),'W', 'H'),'X', 'I'),'Y', 'J'), '1', '9'),'2','8'),'3','7'),'4','6'),'5','5'),'6','4'),'7','3'),'8','2'),'9','1'),' ','')

Select @Input = @Prestring + @Substring + @Poststring

 SELECT @i = @i + 1


 print 'END
 '

 END
```

This doesnt work correctly though, the code does not execute as its written, any suggestions?

Comment: pls provide your SQL Server version and a working example demonstrating this behaviour. I do not see this issue on my SQL Server 2005 instance

Comment: ..?   replace('abc','a','b') = bbc

Comment: MS SQL server 2008 (installed with Mgment studio). Working example is;

Comment: Your best option might be to write a user defined function.  By the way, this function is often called "tr" or "translate" after the unix command of the same name.

Comment: SELECT * INTO example_temp FROM example; 
Update KAP_db.dbo.example_temp Set col1 = replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace
(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace
(col1, 'A', 'N'),'B', 'O'), 'C', 'P'), 'D', 'Q'), 'E', 'R'), 'F', 'S'), 'G', 'T'), 'H', 'U'), 'I', 'V'), 'J', 'W'), 'K', 'X'), 'L', 'Y'), 'M', 'Z'), 'O', 'A'), 'P', 'B'), 'Q', 'C')

Comment: , 'R', 'D'),'S', 'E'),'T', 'E'),'U', 'E'),'V', 'F'),'W', 'G'),'X', 'H'),'Y', 'I'),'Z', 'J'), '1', '9'),'2','8'),'3','7'),'4','6'),'5','5'),'6','4'),'7','3'),'8','2'),'9','1'),' ','');

The above results in '8EVHUAB' and '8EVHHAB' outoutting '2DFEENA'

Comment: Please **do not** put code samples or sample data into comments - since you cannot format it, it's **extremely hard** to read it.... Instead: **update** your question by editing it to provide that additional information! Thank you.

Comment: @user1417337 You're missing `Replace('N', 'something')`. Please delete your comments. They are too long.

Comment: @Marc_s - thansk, i will do that next time - new to posting!

Comment: @user1417337: no worries - we all live and learn every day :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Why you're seeing this:* `replace` is a function; all it knows are its arguments. `replace(replace('aba', 'a', 'b'), 'b', 'a')` is absolutely equivalent to `replace('bbb', 'b', 'a')`, because the outer `replace` has no way of knowing that its first argument was created by a different call to `replace`. Does that make sense?

You can think of it just like a function in algebra. If we define f(x) = x<sup>2</sup>, then f(f(2)) = f(2<sup>2</sup>) = f(4) = 4<sup>2</sup> = 16. There's no way to tell f to behave differently when its argument is f(2) from when its argument is 4, because f(2) *is* 4.

Similarly, `replace('aba', 'a', 'b')` *is* `'bbb'`, so there's no way to tell `replace` to behave differently when its first argument is `replace('aba', 'a', 'b')` from when its first argument is `'bbb'`.

(This is usually true in computer science. Functions in computer science aren't always like functions in algebra — for example, they frequently actually *do* things, rather than just returning a value — but it's usually the case that they receive arguments as values, or as opaque references to values, and have no way of knowing where they came from or how they were constructed.)

*How to address this:* I don't think there's any very clean way to do this. Gordon Linoff suggested that you could use intermediate placeholder characters (specifically — lowercase letters) that don't exist in the initial string and don't exist in the final string, so that you can safely `replace` them without worrying about interference; and I think that's probably the best approach.

Comment: Fantastic, that helped me visualise why im going wrong. This makes sense.Now to find a solution!

Answer (score 3):

Your results are not surprising, since each replace is returning the string to the next level.  There is no way to distinguish between the original character value and the replaced value, when they are the same character.

If you were only working with alpha characters you could do the following.

1. Change the collation of the original string.
2. Upper case the string
3. Replace the upper case letters with the lower case
4. Lower case the entire string at the end (should be redundant)

Unfortunately, I can't think of an analog for numbers that would work the same way.

Here is a link to a site that has code for the function http://www.dbforums.com/microsoft-sql-server/1216565-oracle-translate-function-equivalent-sql-server.html.  The equivalent function in Oracle is called translate.

Comment: I'm not sure i follow you, could you provide an example?

Comment: I want to +1 this, but the OP seems very confused about the basics of how functions work and why (s)he's seeing this behavior; I think any answer to this question really needs to start by explaining that.

Comment: yes please - i built this function on the mis-understanding that it would replace each char once. If i knew more about it, i might be able build a less buggy one :).

Comment: This link looks like it could be the answer - il give it a go.

Answer (score 2):

The `Replace()` function simply performs the operation and returns. It doesn't keep state to the next `Replace()`. It doesn't prevent a later invocation from replacing the characters you previously replaced. To cycle characters around, you have to have an additional "placeholder" value, and then take care to not replace a character that was already change from something else.

First, let me show you an analogy:

There are three buckets full of an equal number of marbles. The buckets are labeled "A", "B", and "C". You must perform the following instructions:

- Pour all marbles from A into C.
- Pour all marbles from B into A.
- Pour all marbles from C into B.

What result would you expect to have? The answer is: an empty bucket C, and B having twice the number of marbles as are in A.

If you want to preserve the marbles in their original counts, you have to have four containers so that you don't mix the marbles while moving them:

- Pour all marbles from C into X.
- Pour all marbles from A into C.
- Pour all marbles from B into A.
- Pour all marbles from X into B. (rather than from C--which already has A's marbles)

Now you have the results you expected, and can discard the empty bucket X.

Try this expression and see if it gives what you want:

```
Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace('c', char(1)), 'a', 'c'), 'b', 'a'), char(1), 'b')
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, i know why my solution is not working now ErikE. It is dependent on my nested Replace function checking in the correct order and that is something I cant guarantee. I dont think it is the same issue as your example, it is more a case of dont change a character to another char if you still have to check for that character in a up and coming replace function. 'Replace and stop, then move onto next char string' is what i need to do!

Comment: How can my solution possibly not work for you? Maybe you can show more code?

Comment: Hey ErikE, I am working on it, maybe i have misunderstood your solution but as i see it, my issue is i was applying the replace to the entire string each time. Instead i must systematically step through the strings chars one at a time so i dont change a char > once

Comment: No. You can replace the entire string at once, *as long as* you are careful and have an unused character to be a placeholder. look at my code! I replaced a, b, and c without error!

Comment: I ended up taking every char individually and converting it t unicode and ading or removing a set figure and then converting back.

Comment: Id love to see your code for the entire alphabet as it sounds a neat solution.