# SQL Function to replace multiple characters in string

Tags: string, sql-server-2008, replace, while-loop

I am writing a SQL Server 2008 user-defined function to replace a string's characters with another character. I think the code below should work, but it doesn't. It doesn't seem to be updating the variable for `@input` correctly.

Any idea how I can fix this?

```
 DECLARE @Input AS VarChar(1000)
 DECLARE @i AS TinyInt
 DECLARE @Substring AS VarChar(1000)
 DECLARE @Prestring  AS VarChar(1000)
 DECLARE @Poststring  AS VarChar(1000)

 Select @Input='ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ123456789',
        @i = 1

 WHILE @i <= LEN(@Input) 
 BEGIN
    SELECT @Prestring = SUBSTRING(@Input,-1,@i)
    SELECT @Poststring = SUBSTRING(@Input,@i+1,LEN(@Input))    

    SELECT @Substring =  replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace
(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace
(SUBSTRING(@Input,@i,1), 'A', 'N'),'B', 'O'), 'C', 'P'), 'D', 'Q'), 'E', 'R'), 'F', 'S'), 'G', 'T'), 'H', 'U'), 'I', 'V'), 'J', 'W'), 'K', 'X'), 'L', 'Y'), 'M', 'Z'), 'N', 'A'), '0', 'B'), 'P', 'C')
, 'Q', 'D'),'R', 'E'),'S', 'E'),'T', 'E'),'U', 'F'),'V', 'G'),'W', 'H'),'X', 'I'),'Y', 'J'), '1', '9'),'2','8'),'3','7'),'4','6'),'5','5'),'6','4'),'7','3'),'8','2'),'9','1'),' ','')

    SELECT @Input = @Prestring + @Substring + @Poststring
    SELECT @i = @i + 1

    PRINT 'Prestring= ' + @Prestring PRINT 'SUBSTRING= ' + @Substring PRINT 'PostString= '     + @Poststring PRINT 'Total String: ' + @Prestring + ' + ' + @Substring + ' + ' + @Poststringenter code here

    PRINT 'END'

 END

Output:
Prestring= 
SUBSTRING= A
PostString= BCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ123456789
Total String:  + A + BCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ123456789
1
END

Prestring= A
SUBSTRING= O
PostString= CDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ123456789
Total String: A + O + CDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ123456789
2
END

Prestring= AO
SUBSTRING= C
PostString= DEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ123456789
Total String: AO + C + DEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ123456789
3
END

Prestring= AOC
SUBSTRING= D
PostString= EFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ123456789
Total String: AOC + D + EFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ123456789
4
END

......
```

Comment: Any other detail? DBMS? symptoms?

Comment: What value of @input are you expecting at the end of the ride? And what is it giving you now?

Comment: Apologies, MS SQL 2008.
I can post the output i am getting but verified it is same on another system running SQL2008

Comment: How did you arrive at such an ugly looking select @Substring statement.  My advice is to create a function that returns an empty string and then pass in A and fix the code in the function to return the correct value. Do this for each individual character.  Once you can process one character at a time you can worry about processing multiple characters.

Comment: I expect NMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ987654321

Comment: Wasn't this [discussed earlier](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11636147/sql-server-how-does-the-replace-function-work-as-its-acting-strange-for-me)?

Comment: @Nikola - yes but i wasn't sure if i should open a new thread as its effectively a diff issue as  i have re-written the code seeing last function was flawed.

Comment: @Andrew - would this not mean using the same replace code in the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another way that will work bidirectionally:

```
declare @input nvarchar(max) = N'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ123456789'
    , @output nvarchar(max) = N''
    , @i int = 1

while @i <= len(@input) begin
    declare @unicode int = unicode(substring(@input, @i, 1))
    select @output = @output + nchar(
            case
                when @unicode between 65 and 77 then @unicode + 13
                when @unicode between 78 and 90 then @unicode - 13
                when @unicode between 49 and 57 then 106 - @unicode
                else @unicode
            end
        )
        , @i = @i + 1
end

select @input as VerySimpleCipher
union all
select @output
```

I'd probably use a table variable as a map if you were doing more conditions.  You may want to add handling of lower-case letters, zeros, nulls, etc.  Also, I would caution against using this as some type of cipher for anything other than fun.

Comment: This is a good method! thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

Recheck your conversions.

You convert C->P and then a later replace updates it as P->C.

Each replace is sequential from the innermost call. You should break these out into a function and return once it matches something the first time.

Comment: Yes, thanks, i thought i had fixed issue by only looking ta 1 char at a time but i havnt :(

Answer (score 0):

This should get you started...

```
-- A should return N
select dbo.ConvertChars('A');
-- B should return O
select dbo.ConvertChars('B');


--create function dbo.ConvertChars(@input char(1))
alter function dbo.ConvertChars(@input char(1))
returns char(1)
begin


    IF @input='A' return 'N';   
    IF @input='B' return 'O';


    return '';

end
```

Comment: Thanks Andrew but does this not hit the same issue as i have - Say i have 1 character in my string -A. I will end up converting like this; A->N->A, resulting in A!

Comment: That is more a logic problem you are speaking about.  If you followed what I have done above you would be able to solve the problem you mention in an outer function.  i.e. use a while loop to process each character at a time and build the result in a new string

Comment: I ended up using ASCII conversion and adjusted its value before converting back to give me a new character.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this, but it would follow on from the code above.  It should at least give you an idea on how you could do this.

```
create function dbo.ConvertCharString(@input varchar(1000))
returns varchar(1000)
begin
declare @id int
declare @len int
declare @c vhar(1)
declare @return varchar(1000)
        SET @idx = 0
        SELECT @idx = CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @str)
        SELECT @len = len(@input)

        -- loop through delimiter sep. list until no more comma's found i.e. charindex returns 0
        while  (@idx <= @len)
        begin
            set @c = substring(@input, @idx, 1)
            select @return = @return + dbo.ConvertChars(@c)
            select @idx = @idx-1
        end


end
```

Comment: Hey Andrew - it exhibits the same issue - A would be replaced by N which in turn is replaced by A. Im experimenting with breaks but they kill my While loop

Comment: Actually, i think i misread this, il try it

Answer (score 0):

See below for my answer! Thanks to all, this was harder than it should have been for me!

create function dbo.Translate(@Input varchar(1000))
    RETURNS VARCHAR (1000)
    BEGIN

```
DECLARE @i AS Int
Declare @SingleChar_Offset AS VarChar(1000)
Declare @Output AS VarChar(1000)
DECLARE @Unicode_Offset AS Int
DECLARE @UnicodeChar AS Int


SELECT @i = 1
Select @Output = ''


WHILE @i <= LEN(@Input) 
BEGIN
  Select @UnicodeChar = unicode(substring(@Input, @i, 1))

    IF @UnicodeChar <=52
      BEGIN
            Select @Unicode_Offset = @UnicodeChar+5
      END
  ELSE IF @UnicodeChar >52 AND @UnicodeChar <=57
      BEGIN
            Select @Unicode_Offset = @UnicodeChar-5
      END

  IF @UnicodeChar >= 65 AND @UnicodeChar <=77
      BEGIN
            Select @Unicode_Offset = @UnicodeChar+13
      END
  ELSE IF @UnicodeChar > 77
      BEGIN
            Select @Unicode_Offset = @UnicodeChar-13
      END

  Select @SingleChar_Offset = CHAR(@Unicode_Offset)
  SELECT @i = @i + 1   
  --PRINT @SingleChar_Offset
     Select @Output = @Output + @SingleChar_Offset
-- print 'END
-- '

END

--PRINT @Output

RETURN @Output

END
```